# If/Else result based off of user input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

So I'm new to java and a bit confused. I learn best by taking what I've just been taught and creating my own little programs with it, just to help understand the principles at work.

I'm having an issue learning how to use a user input and equaling it to something. Essentially I want a user to input their gender, and based on their answer, get a response using if/else. This is all of the code I have right now pertaining to the area, and I'm really confused on how to go about getting their answer from the input, and then checking it using if/else.

```
Scanner four = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("So, what gender did you say you were?");

//Add if/else statement response here that will be called based on user input
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can we see it?

Answer (score 2):

First, get the response from the user...

```
Scanner four = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("So, what gender did you say you were?");

// What the user said...
String response = four.nextLine();
```

Then, use `String.equals` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase` to test the result...

```
if ("M".equalsIgnoreCase(response) || "MALE".equalsIgnoreCase(response)) {
    // If the user responded with "m" or "male"...
} else if ... {// set up female response
} else {
    // Default response...
}
```

When stuck, consider checking out the offical tutorials, for example [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is a detailed answer. I was lacking the part String response = four.nextLine(); I guess this is the program checking and recognizing what the user said? Essentially the results? And then we reference the results in the if/else.

Comment: `nextLine` is reading the response from the user (waiting till the press the enter key), the `if/else if/else` is you dealing with that response in what ever way you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("So, what gender did you say you were?");
String four=input.nextLine();

if(four.equals("xyz"){
 //Do something
}
else{
  //Do Something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I was missing the part concerning String four=input.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the quick responses! This was the piece of code I was missing..

```
String four=input.nextLine();
```